# Centering a checkbox within a div while using FontAwesome to replace the checkbox and changing the div color

Tags: html, css, checkbox, font-awesome

I have been toying with this for hours and decided to ask.  I am trying to replace my checkboxes with Font Awesome icons within a circle div.  When the checkbox is checked the circle color is supposed to change.

I have managed to get the icons to replace the checkboxes, but I can not get the background to change when selected.  I personally think I over thought this and it could probally be done much simpler, but this is what I have.

HTML:

```
<div class="actions thread-actions">
   <div class="checkbox visible">
      <button class="action primary-action visible" title="$vbphrase[save_changes]">
         <label for="cb_visible"><input type="checkbox" name="visible" value="yes" id="cb_visible" checked /></label>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS: (SCSS)

```
$brand-success: #5cb85c !default;
$brand-danger: #d9534f !default;

.thread-actions .checkbox {
   input[type=checkbox] {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -100em;
      margin-right: 100em;
      font-size: 1em;
   }

   input[type=checkbox]:before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 99em;
   }
}

/* Colors ---------------------- */
.thread-actions input[type=checkbox]:checked {
   color: $brand-success;
}

.thread-actions {
   input[type=checkbox]:before {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   }
}

.thread-actions {
   .checkbox.visible input[type=checkbox]:before {
      content: "\f023";
      margin: -22px 0px 0px 17px;
   }
   .checkbox.visible input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
      content: "\f023";
      background-color: #ff0000;
      /*  f3c2  */
   }
}

.actions .action {
   font-size: 26px;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 48px;
   width: 48px;
   position: relative;
}
```

How can I achieve this effect?

I have a live [PEN here](https://codepen.io/-GiR/pen/KKMLEjj) where I have been playing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting from scratch and re-thinking this through, I managed to come up with a solution.

Instead of enclosing the input with pointless *divs*, then trying to style each div I worked with only the *input*.

To achieve this effect, start by pushing the standard checkmark out of the way:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';        // tell this element to use FA
  position: absolute;                // absolutely push this thing away
  margin-left: -100em;               // buh bye checkmark
  font-size: 26px;                   // FA icon size
}
```

With the checkbox out of the way we can move on to styling as we wish:

```
input[type=checkbox]:before {
  left: 100em;                   // where the checkmark should have been
  border-radius: 50%;            // circle
  position: absolute;            // we want it absolutely where we placed it
  text-align: center;            // FontAwesome icon alignment
  height: 40px;                  // height of the circle
  width: 40px;                   // width of the circle
  background-color: #337ab7;     // circle color
  color: white;                  // icon color
  content: "\f070";              // FA icon
}
```

With this as a base we can move on to styling our checked boxes by simply overriding our base style:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
  content: "\f06e";                // FA icon
  background-color:#be0000;        // circle color
}
```

Sometimes going back and rethinking things helps, hope this helps someone =)

[Here is a live preview of the end result.](https://codepen.io/-GiR/pen/MWedRJK)